# display error on my newsletter after sending, not on local view

Tags: html, dreamweaver

`enter code here`I am working on an html newsletter via Dreamweaver, sent then via SendinBlue.
While I am working on it, display looks perfectly good.
Once I send a test, few stuff are not display correctly, at least, as it's supposed to be.
The funniest thing of all that, is that I've made LOTS of test, on my professional Outlook email address, on my personal one and displays are different, still not like supposed to be but the display errors are not the same. So it is clear I've made a mistake, somewhere, but can't figure out where and how to fix it.
Need help, please.
I know Dreamweaver is old and all, but that's the only software I can and know how to use. I don't want to switch for another software, start all over again while I only need to fix 1% of my job.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pL0j.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYm1d.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFJ1A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf1TZ.png)

L'ACTUALITÉ IT

```
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w100 showonmobile" style="width: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <img src="file:///P|/Marketing/Communication Interne/NEWSLETTER PARTENAIRES/2021 Q3 - Newsletter/images/debrief-sim.gif" alt="l'actualité IT" style="display: block;border: 0px;" width="100%" height="auto" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align: center;">
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <table bgcolor="#d2e8f0" width="550" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w80">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 30px 0px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                                        <table bgcolor="#d2e8f0" width="160" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;color: #23386e;font-weight: 300;font-family: 'Akrobat',arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 17px;padding-bottom: 30px;background: url('file:///P|/Marketing/Communication Interne/NEWSLETTER PARTENAIRES/2021 Q3 - Newsletter/images/01.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:47px 113px;background-position:left top;padding-top: 15px;">
                                                        Comment sécuriser gratuitement vos comptes d’administrateurs au sein de votre réseau ?
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-bottom: 8px;padding-top:8px;text-align: center;font-family: 'Akrobat',arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 19px;font-weight: bold;background-color: #23386e;">
                                                    <a href="https://www.bytheway.fr/microsoft-laps/" title="LIRE LA SUITE" target="_blank" style="color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;display: block;">
                                                        LIRE  LA SUITE
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                        <table bgcolor="#d2e8f0" width="160" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;color: #23386e;font-weight: 300;font-family: 'Akrobat',arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 17px;padding-bottom: 30px;background: url('file:///P|/Marketing/Communication Interne/NEWSLETTER PARTENAIRES/2021 Q3 - Newsletter/images/02.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:80px 115px;background-position:left top;padding-top: 15px;">
                                                Une seule faille suffit à vous nuire. Gérez vos vulnérabilités en maîtrisant votre surface d'attaque.
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-bottom: 8px;padding-top:8px;text-align: center;font-family: 'Akrobat',arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 19px;font-weight: bold;background-color: #23386e;">
                                                    <a href="https://www.bytheway.fr/?p=113325&preview=true" title="LIRE LA SUITE" target="_blank" style="color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;display: block;">
                                                LIRE LA SUITE
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    
                                        <table bgcolor="#d2e8f0" width="160" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;color: #23386e;font-weight: 300;font-family: 'Akrobat',arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 17px;padding-bottom: 30px;background: url('file:///P|/Marketing/Communication Interne/NEWSLETTER PARTENAIRES/2021 Q3 - Newsletter/images/03.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:80px 115px;background-position:left top;padding-top: 15px;">
                                                L'IA à la rescousse des attaques sophistiquées dès le premier email pour Microsoft 365.                                 </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-bottom: 8px;padding-top:8px;text-align: center;font-family: 'Akrobat',arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 19px;font-weight: bold;background-color: #23386e;">
                                                    <a href="https://www.bytheway.fr/une-messagerie-securisee-pour-microsoft-365-en-utilisant-lia" title="LIRE LA SUITE" target="_blank" style="color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;display: block;">
                                                    LIRE LA SUITE
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: This seems to be a CSS issue. Are you linking an external CSS file that maybe you are not including in the final email template?

Would help to see the code.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for taking the time!
There is no CSS file, at least, I mean, I think so. I did not code the entire thing, an ex colleague of mine did. I took over the file and modify as much as I need.

Comment: I've edited the original post with the code in question